# BTRFS Mounting 2 subvolumes

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, fstab, btrfs

I've got a BTRFS volume setup with this subvolume structure.

```
ThePool  
   |  
   |  
 Media
   |
   |--------Movies    
   |  
   |--------TV Shows
```

Basically I'm setting up my computer to be a server with plex running and stuff like that.

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu and I want to mount the Movies and TVShows directories to `/home/{username}/Videos/Movies` and `/home/{username}/Videos/TVShows` respectively.

This allows me to have plex point at those two directories and I won't have to go back and update them if I decide to switch to ZFS or something else. The problem I come across is that when I try to mount both of them it won't work at all.

My fstab looks like the following:

```
/dev/sda   /home/{username}/Videos/Movies   btrfs defaults,compress=zlib,autodefrag,subvol=Media/Movies 0  0
/dev/sda   /home/{username}/Videos/TVShows   btrfs defaults,compress=zlib,autodefrag,subvol=Media/TVShows 0  0
```

Whichever one of these I put on top is the only one that gets mounted after a reboot. If I put TVShows on top TVShows gets mounted in TVShows, but nothing happens with Movies and vice-versa.

If I take it all out of the fstab and then just run these individually then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Does adding `,remount` after `defaults` work?